# Can't open files in directory using cat in bash

Tags: bash, directory, cat

Hey guys I'm trying to run a shell script which searches for a directory and then checks the files of the directory to see if it can find a specific name. Basic stuff. The directory is named labs and it's under my home directory. The files have no file extension. The script needs to be run in my home directory. I'm trying to open all files and search for the specific name. This is a line in the script that causes me trouble :

`ls labs | xargs cat | grep name`

And I get the following error:

`cat: cannot open name_of_file`

For every file I find. Why doesn't this work outside of the directory but when I'm inside it's fine. How can I make it work? My bash doesn't have the open command.

Comment: why are you doing this? can you just `grep foo labs/*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the output of `ls labs`.  It's a list of bare filenames -- that is, filenames with no directory prefix.  So you get output like:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

When you pass this to `xargs`, you end up running a command like:

```
cat file1 file2 file3
```

But since you're not inside the `labs` directory (you're in the parent), these filenames refer to files that don't exist.  You would need to either first cd into the `labs` directory:

```
cd labs; ls | xargs cat | grep name
```

Or use a command like `find` that returns full paths:

```
find labs -type f | xargs cat | grep name
```

Comment: I like the last example. I think the OP was using the command ls like it was the command find.

Comment: @larsks Thanks so much for the answer that solved. Didn't know find returns full paths, so thanks for the explanation too.